# Adding checked attribute via jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, addition, checked

I am using the following widget
http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/
It has worked great so far, but I need some help in adding attributes. In using Firebug, I've noticed that by simply clicking on the checkbox the checked attribute does not appear as I would expect it to. In my code, I've modified the widget, I've been able to add code to remove the attribute of checked.

```
this.removeAttribute(\'checked\'); this.checked=false;
```

if the item was checked beforehand. I've been successful in using this code

```
this.setAttribute(\'checked\', \'checked\'); this.checked=true;
```

if the item was unchecked when the page loads.

My problem is coming when I need to be able to utilize both sets of code on the checkbox, I've attempted the following

```
onclick="if($(this).attr(\'checked\') == \'true\') { this.setAttribute(\'checked\', \'checked\'); this.checked=true; } else { this.removeAttribute(\'checked\'); this.checked=false; }
```

the code will remove the attribute of checked (if checked before hand on page load), but when I attempt to click on the checkbox to add the attribute (if not checked on page load), nothing happens.

Thanks for any help, and sorry for my poor coding.

Comment: Thanks Guys. The reason for this is that I'm attempting to perform a toggle() event on the optgroup header. When a user clicks this, it will collapse the section associated with it, however, it will show the items that are checked. It works if you toggle the event back and forth without checking/unchecking an item. The problem I am having though is that if you have an item that is checked on page load, the toggle() will work. If you uncheck it, the toggle() will not work for that item because I am looking at the checked attribute. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: you do not need to escape single quotes that are wrapped in double quotes

Answer (score 23):

In jQuery for removing an attribute use

```
this.removeAttr('checked');
```

and for setting an attribute use

```
this.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(this).prop('checked',false)
```

or

```
$(this).prop('checked',true)
```

Comment: Is this equivalent to $(this).attr("checked","checked");?

Comment: This is the preferred answer to jQuery 3.0+ (https://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 2):

> I've noticed that by simply clicking on the checkbox the checked attribute does not appear

That's absolutely correct. The `checked` attribute *does not* correspond to the current checkedness of the input; it actually corresponds to the initial checkedness from the HTML document, the checkedness that will be reinstated if the form is reset.

IE adds the attribute because IE is wrong. `getAttribute`/`setAttribute` are broken in IE—never use them on an HTML document!—they actually set the property, not the attribute.

This is the `defaultChecked` property. But why are you trying to set the `checked` attribute? There is almost never a good reason to. Normally the plain old `checked` property is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> In using Firebug, I've noticed that by simply clicking on the checkbox the checked attribute does not appear as I would expect it to.

Why do you need the `checked` attribute at all? The `checked` property provides all the functionality that you would normally need, i.e. checking the box will set `element.checked` to `true` and vice versa, i.e. modifying `element.checked` will change the state of the box.

Comment: I'm ultimately using the checked property to toggle the optgroups for a show/hide effect. If the code finds that an item is checked when the toggle event is triggered, then show the items that are checked, if not hide them. Is there another way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: You just need to use the `checked` property of the element, for eg. `$('#id')[0].checked`